# Does Doctrine support SQLite 2 databases?

Tags: database, sqlite, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've a legacy SQLite 2 database I need to work with. Does Doctrine 2.4 support SQLite 2? I've tried to open a `test.sqlite` database; listing all tables doesn't work:

```
$conn = Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(
    array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_sqlite',
        'user'     => null,
        'password' => null,
        'path'     => '/path/to/test.sqlite'
    ),
    new Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration()
);

$sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();

var_dump($sm->listTableNames()); // Empty array
```

No errors, just an empty array.

Comment: Why can't you convert the database to version 3?

Comment: @CL. because the sqlite file is produced by a legacy desktop app..